# how to plot rows of a column in loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a data frame and I want to plot rows of a column in a loop

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['joe', 'sue', 'mike'],
    'x': ['0,1,5,3,4,5', '0,4,4,2,8', '0,4,6,7,8,9,0'],
    'y': ['0,3,8', '1,9,5', '1,6,4,5,6,2,3,4,6']
})


print(df)



name              x                  y
0   joe    0,1,5,3,4,5              0,3,8
1   sue      0,4,4,2,8              1,9,5
2  mike  0,4,6,7,8,9,0  1,6,4,5,6,2,3,4,6
```

I want to plot every rows of x for example i will plot `0,1,5,3,4,5` then `0,4,4,2,8` then `0,4,6,7,8,9,0`  in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for row in df['x'].str.split(','):  # explode string
    data = np.array(row).astype(float)  # convert str to float
    ax.plot(data)
ax.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y axis')
ax.set_title('My figure')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: suppose i want to plot only  0,1,5,3,4,5 where should i change can u please suggest

Comment: should i change df['x'] to df['x'][1]  ???